# How to create the the same fragment several times into a Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a fragment to register customer addresses (called "address") that contains a "+" button.

I want to create another fragment below this containing the same content so that the customer can add as many addresses as he wants to.

I know it's possible to create components one by one programatically. But, this fragmet is a bit complex and I dont want to create it dynamically.

Is that possible to insert the same fragment several times inside a layout of the fragment itself?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    LinearLayout newlayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    newlayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    newlayout.setId(ConfigFragment.generateViewId());
    LinearLayout parentlayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.regpet_frame_main);
    parentlayout.addView(newlayout);
    ConfigFragment.openFragment(new RegPetFragment(), newlayout.getId(), getChildFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.title_reg_pet));
}
```

Surely new questions will come!!!

Comment: You'd be better off with a class that `extends View` rather than `extends Fragment`

Comment: @cricket , should I just change `extends Fragment ` for `extends View`?

Comment: It's not that easy no. My point was that Fragment seems overkill for what you seem to be doing with dynamic layouts.

Comment: @cricket_007, I'm a newbe here! If you could help me with this, I'd be very tankful! Is there a link to a tutorial or something else that could help me?

Comment: I don't have anything, sorry. I'll phrase the question this way: Why are you not using an `ArrayAdapter` to load a `ListView`? Even if you didn't want it to scroll, that is essentially what I think you've done here.